# CL Eye dll importing issues

Tags: c#, cl

I am trying to run a program called Free3dTrack that  uses the CLEye drivers, but the program isnt showing any cameras connected. How do you check where the program is importing its dlls from if it uses the dllimport command in C#.

Comment: do you have to create an environment variable for the dlls?